# Как отфильтровать по параметрам запроса, отношение многим ко многим

Tags: python, django, запрос, django-rest-framework

Хочу отфильтровать по параметрам запроса (по id).

К примеру: http://.../themes/?category=1&level=1

---

model.py

```
class Themes(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    level = models.ManyToManyField(Level)
```

views.py

```
class ThemesListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ThemesListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Themes.objects.all()
        category = self.request.query_params.get('category')
        level = self.request.query_params.get('level')

        if category:
            queryset = queryset.filter(category_id=category)

        if level:
            queryset = queryset.filter(level=level)

        return queryset
```

Ожидаю:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "category": 1,
    "level": [
        1
   ]
}
```

Получаю:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "category": 1,
    "level": [
        1,
        2
    ]
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно исправить код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема возникает из-за того, что все предикаты добавленные в `queryset` с помощью `filter`, используется только для фильтрации объектов, которые возвращает `queryset`, т.е. в даном случае `Themes`.

Это значит, что выполняется запрос "верни мне все Themes, у которых есть такой то level". Данные для модели `Level` достаются отдельными запросами уже когда происходит сериализация `Themes` и идет доступ к полю `level`.

Чтоб это исправить нужно сконфигурировать запрос так, чтоб ассоциированные `Level` доставались в том же запросе (ну и при этом наложить фильтр, который укажет выбирать не все). Для этого нужно воспользоваться [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) как-то так:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

...

if level:
    # тут предполагается, что фильтруем по полю id в Level
    queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(
         Prefetch('level', queryset=Level.objects.filter(id=level)))l
```

Comment: можно ли сделать так, чтобы выводился не список level-ов, а одно значение?
К примеру {
    "id": 1,
    "category": 1,
    "level": 
        1
}

Comment: Можно. Нужно изменить `ThemesListSerializer`

Comment: Нужно изменить поле level?

Comment: Нужно задать отдельный вопрос, с кодом и т.д.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо :)